# Firestore not conecting on react native android

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

Firestore connects if I run in Web brower but not on the android emulator, neither in the fiscal device.

I get the fallowing error and a empty Array = []

```
[2021-10-23T19:28:23.329Z]  @firebase/firestore:, Firestore (9.1.3): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds.
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
at node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
at node_modules\@firebase\util\dist\index.esm2017.js:1754:9 in stringLength
at http://192.168.0.102:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:130185:28 in error
at node_modules\@firebase\auth\dist\rn\enum_maps-81db3ff6.js:6991:20 in <global>
at node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.rn.js:10137:8 in <global>
at http://192.168.0.102:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:149276:48 in <unknown>
at node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.rn.js:10653:10 in <global>
at node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.rn.js:14006:24 in <global>
at node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.rn.js:14048:19 in cancel
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:248:12 in _allocateCallback$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:112:14 in _callTimer
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:166:14 in _callReactNativeMicrotasksPass
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:418:41 in callReactNativeMicrotasks
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:393:6 in __callReactNativeMicrotasks
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:135:6 in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:370:10 in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:134:4 in flushedQueue
```

"firebase": "^9.1.3", "react": "17.0.1", "react-native": "^0.66.1".

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import { auth,db } from '../firebase'
import { collection, getDocs} from 'firebase/firestore';
import { onAuthStateChanged,signOut } from "firebase/auth";
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/core';


const HomeScreen = () => {
const [user, setUser] = useState()
const [trials, setTrials] = useState([])
const trialsCollectionRef = collection(db,"trials")

    useEffect(()=> {
        const getTrials = async () =>{
            const data = await getDocs(trialsCollectionRef)
            console.log(data.docs.map((doc)=>({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})))
            setTrials(data.docs.map((doc)=>({...doc.data(),id: doc.id})))
        }
        getTrials()
    },[])
```

firebase.js

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
        //...
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app)
const db = getFirestore(app)

export {auth, db}
```

And if I use import { collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore/lite'; it connects
How can I make Firestore work, and why is it behaving this way?